# React material-ui, grid list cannot render grid

Tags: reactjs

```
<div>
     <div style={styles.root}>
          <GridList cols={3} padding={50} cellHeight={300} style={styles.gridList}>

               {Object.keys(appList).map(key => {
                    return (<DistributedViewAppThumbnail distributedApp={appList[key]}
                                                                 currentTime={new Date().getTime()}/>

                            )
                        })};

           </GridList>
      </div>
 </div>
```

when I render GridList it throws an exception like this

```
bundle.js:22 TypeError: Cannot read property 'cols' of undefined
```

View from console below.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLefw.png)

Comment: Are u sure this error belongs to shared code?There is no `cols` in shared code

Comment: Have you imported `GridList` ? Also the `MuiThemeProvider`?

Comment: @AmanshuKataria  yes I have imported. But If I write GridList inside 
{Object.keys(appList).map(key => {....} it works fine. but I need to declare it outside the method

Comment: @James remove `;` at the end of `{Object.keys(appList).map(key => {....} ;`

Comment: @AmanshuKataria yeah that's the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: @James kindly accept the answer to help others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSX expressions are limited to `{}`. However, you can use `;` inside `{}`.

Removing `;` from `{Object.keys(appList).map(key => {....};` will solve your issue.